# Object persistence (between post-backs) in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am in the process of developing a quite large web app. Multiple levels of access have been defined via ASP.NET Membership and Role providers. Individual users also have profiles (which I have extended to include a variety of arbitrary info).

The question is how do I persist the user between post backs?

I could use something like HttpContext.Current to store the user, but its lifespan is only from one post-back to another. It's my understanding that I would have to retrieve the user object at the beginning of the post-back (OnInit/PageLoad) and then drop it back in the HttpContext at the end of each post-back. Seems kind of inefficient.

(I wonder if i can do this with an HttpModule?)

Also, even though there is a static CurrentUser instance in ASP.NET it is simply a generic User. I need to carry the entire profile (which I created in SQL).

To recap, the question is: a) is it possible to extend the static CurrentUser instance given by ASP.NET so that it would carry arbitrary information while being persisted through normal channels? If No, how can I persist such static information throughout the duration of the User session (until the user either logs off, or the Session Expire/Timeout event is fired by the global.asax)?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!
bleepzter

Comment: I forgot to mention I can't use Session State, or View State.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an IHttpModule that hooks into the PostAuthenticateRequest, then store your user in the HttpContext.Current.User

Example:

```
public class MyModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.PostAuthenticateRequest += PostAuthenticateRequest;
    }

    private void PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var app = (HttpApplication)sender;
        var httpContext = app.Context;
        IMyPrincipal principal = null;

        principal = new MyPrincipal(httpContext.User.Identity);

        httpContext.User = principal;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I have two questions though. What is IMyPrincipal? and MyPrincipal?

Comment: Ok, nevermind, I looked it up - it's the actual PrincipalPermission object.

Comment: @bleepzter, yeah those Principals would be your extension to the built in IPrincipal that is provided to you by ASP.NET

Comment: This seems like a partial answer. The half your missing is the whole `MyPrincipal` part. Even a brief description would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the motivation for this is performance?  In that case, the answer is usually "Cache".  However, If you're running "quite a large web app" without SessionsState, I'm guessing you're planning on a Web Farm, which means you'll probably implement memcached instead.  So, basically, create some lazy-load object that pulls the info from your cache and stores it in the HttpContext.Current.  The next request, repeat process.

My final suggestion is to just let it pull from the database on every request...it might perform well enough without jumping through all of these hoops.